How to prevent white-space between {% set %} and {% block %} in twig without messing up indentation?
Say one has this twig template:
{% set first %}
  {% block some_block %}
    {{- variable -}}
  {% endblock %}
{% endset %}

Passing in an empty string, '' in variable, one can see that dumping out first, as in {{ first }}, results in a string that contains two spaces.  This space likely comes from between {% set first %} and {% block some_block %}.
How might one achieve first containing an empty string with the following preconditions?

The twig template indentation should not be "messed up" to accommodate this.
No post-processing functions like trim should be used.


Whoa!! Whitespace control operators also apply to other constructs!
{% set first -%}
  {% block some_block %}
    {{- variable -}}
  {% endblock %}
{%- endset %}

seems to do the trick!  That's wild!
